# Changing a format using Vim macro

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file with more than 1000lines with the following format with random numbers.

```
1, 4,0,0
56, 710, 65, 3340,
...
...
```

I would like to change this format by inserting these numbers into `digit[number]` into say.

```
digit[1], digit[4], digit[0], digit[0]
digit[56], digit[710], digit[65], digit[3340].
```

How can i do this in Vim.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

try this command:

```
%s/\d\+/digit[&]/g
```

Comment: @powernest it is a command, you have to first go to command line mode by pressing `:`, then type the command, finally , you need press `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use macros as the title says, you will do something like:

1. `gg` to go the to the top of the file
2. press `q<key>` where key is any letter. You will start recording a
   macro.
3. idigit[    -> Will go into insert mode, then will write digit[
4. `<esc>` to go back to normal mode.
5. `e` to go the end of your number.
6. `i]`, to go to insert mode and write the `]` character.
7. `<esc>` to return to normal mode
8. `w` to go to the next number
9. `q` to stop recording the macro
10. press `XX@<key>` where XX is the number of time you want to apply that macro (it can be a bigger number than the number of lines you have in your file, it will stop at the end), and `<key>` being the same thing as in step 1

Macros are very useful in many cases and easier to write than regex, but might not work all the time.

Comment: this problem is not good for macro. because from the example in question, 1)there could be spaces before/after comma, but in desired output, no space in `[..]`. 2)someline ends with comma, some line doesn't. If the two points were just typoes in example. it could be solved by macro, but I won't go with `j`, since you don't know if every line has same number of numbers. we could use `w` approach. it will go to next line automatically.

Comment: I know, but I assumed that all the lines are the same as these ones, why would it be different? I mean, it's hard to think all of the cases when you just have two lines that have the same syntax

Comment: even if every line had same number of numbers, with `w` will be much simpler than the `j` one. it will save your `Repeat steps 3 to 7 until the end of the line.`  with this example, 3 times insertion of `digit[.....` stuffs.

Comment: and that's why I said, macro is not so good for those kind of problem. because you **could** have different cases, but with command line, works for all cases.

Comment: I agree with the w, I'll edit my answer. Usually, I use macros for this kind of stuff, and I edit manually the edge cases. But I agree, it's not as efficient as a regex in theses cases